# Conditional inside jQuery onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick, conditional-statements

When the site is loaded fullscreen will be set as false

```
    var fullscreen = false;
```

Then I want to do different things to a multiple amount of divs depending on whether fullscreen is true or false.

```
        var fullscreen = false;

fullscreen.on('click', function(){
    if (fullscreen == false) {
        fullscreen = true;
        backgroundCurtain.css({"background" : "black", "padding" : "0"});
        pictureInner.css({"width": "100%"});
        fullscreen.css({"backgroundPosition" : "-26px 0"});
        pictureContainer.css({"width" : "auto", "padding" : "0"});
        imageResized.css({"maxHeight" : "100%", "maxWidth" : "100%"});
        var imageWidth = imageResized.width();
        pictureInner.css({"width" : imageWidth});
        alert(imageWidth);
    }
    else if (fullscreen == true) {
        fullscreen = false;
        backgroundCurtain.removeAttr("style").children().removeAttr("style");
    }
});
```

This doesn't work at all, and I don't know why?

for those who want to debug it on a live site, try pressing any picture on the site; https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9677524/Webbdesign/william.html (scripts doesnt work on Chrome if uploaded to public Dropbox page, afaik)

Comment: Are all those objects (imageResized, pictureInner, etc) defined somewhere? Certainly there's one error: you are using fullscreen.css. The "fullscreen" variable is a boolean, not an object that can have the .css() method called on it.

Comment: @GregPettit Oh snap, it might just be because there are 2 variables named "fullscreen".. How retarded by me, and yes they are defined.

edit: Changed name of the boolean and it worked now.. I make such stupid and simple mistakes when I've coded for too long.

Comment: We have ALL done something like that before. Don't worry too much. ;-) Glad it's working!